# Azure DevOps Extension Process on Delete

Tags: azure, tfs, azure-devops, azure-devops-extensions

I'm developing Azure DevOps extension. When client download extension he can register in Azure Hub then his account is added to my database.

When the client delete extension his account should also be removed from my database.

How can I add process for Azure DevOps extension that can be triggered on uninstall / remove extension?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is an API for this, but you can see uninstalls here in the Marketplace portal. I guess you could poll this, or figure out the underlying API that's being used. any integration against these APIs is unsupported.

```
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/manage/publishers/{PublisherID}/extensions/{ExtensionID}/hub?_a=uninstall
```

[image]

Also, remember that for troubleshooting purposes people uninstall/reinstall extensions and they may need to reinstall as part of migration/upgrade scenarios for which their assumption is likely going to be that no data is lost in the progress.

It's probably best to ask for contact details, upon registration, monitor usage and warn that data will be removed after X days of no usage.

Comment: I want a way to trigger a process to delete account from my server when extension is removed / deleted

Comment: I know, as I said, there is no built-in solution.

Comment: You'll have to rethink your solution.